# if-condition for next command

Tags: environments, ifthenelse, technical-environment

After I started building my own environments, I was wondering, if there is a if-condition, that checks what the next command is, and then gives the option to run something before the next command. A Pseudocode example for what I'm searching for:

```
\newenvironment{test}{
    ifnext{\begin{itemize}}{true: do something}{false: do other things}
    }
    {
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LaTeX has the macro `\@ifnextchar`. The name might be a bit misleading, you can not only use it to test the next single char, but also for a macro with a defined meaning, e.g., you can test whether the next thing in the input stream is `\begin`.

This can be used to build a macro `\ifnextenv`. It will take three arguments, the name of the environment, code which will be executed if that environment is following it, and code which is executed else. The macro will check whether the next thing in the input stream (after its three arguments) is `\begin`. If that's the case it will check whether the first argument to `\begin` matches the first argument to `\ifnextenv` using `\pdf@strcmp`.

Then it'll insert the branches according to the results of the test.

This usage example uses `\ifnextenv` to automatically insert an `itemize` if after `\begin{test}` no `\begin{enumerate}` follows.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{pdftexcmds}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\ifnextenv[3]
  {%
    \@ifnextchar\begin{\@ifnextenv{#1}{#2}{#3}}{#3}%
  }
\newcommand\@ifnextenv[5]
  {%
    \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{#1}{#5}=0
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
    {#2}
    {#3}%
    \begin{#5}%
  }
\makeatother

\newenvironment{test}
  {%
    \ifnextenv{enumerate}
      {\def\test@end{}}
      {\def\test@end{\enditemize}\itemize}%
  }
  {%
    \test@end
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{test}
\item foo
\item bar
\end{test}

\begin{test}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item foo
    \item bar
  \end{enumerate}
\end{test}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry that it took so long: I tried to implement your code into my template, but I can't make it work. I wanted to make a \vspace if a thmtool box starts with an itemize-environment, because otherwise there is always a litte gap. I tried a lot but I always failed :c

Comment: It has to be the very last thing in your macro (except for its arguments).

Comment: I'm sure I did the same thing yesterday and it did not work... Anyway now it works, thank you very much, it solved a big problem! (For future people reading this: Change \test if you are in a different environment and you can run code after @end{})

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do it with a token-cycle.

Every time I find a `\begin{itemize}`, I pre-execute `\PREitemize`, which here I set to `\par Hi Mom, I am about to itemize`.  If there is a `\begin` detected but it is not `itemize`, I pre-execute `\PREbegin`, here set to `\par Sorry, this begin is not itemize`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\def\ITM{itemize}
\def\TRUESET{T}
\def\PREitemize{\par Hi Mom, I am about to itemize}
\def\PREbegin{\par Sorry, this begin is not itemize}
\stripgroupingtrue
\tokcycleenvironment\finditemize
{\addcytoks{##1}}
{\tctestifx{\TRUESET\BEGgo}%
  {\def\tmp{##1}\tctestifx{\ITM\tmp}%
    {\addcytoks[1]{\PREitemize}}{\addcytoks[1]{\PREbegin}}
    \addcytoks{\begin{##1}}}%
  {\addcytoks{{##1}}}%
 \def\BEGgo{F}%
}
{\tctestifx{\begin##1}{\def\BEGgo{T}}{\addcytoks{##1}}}
{\addcytoks{##1}}
\begin{document}
\finditemize
Here is a test
\begin{itemize}
\item A
\begin{itemize}
\item A.1
\item A.2
\end{itemize}
\item B
\item C
\end{itemize}
\begin{enumerate}
\item A
\item B
\item C
\end{enumerate}
\endfinditemize
\end{document}
```

[image]